# due to consider adding?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

I don't quite understand why they use "due to" in this sentence. Can somenone explain it to me?

> Unesco's World Heritage Committee is **due to** consider adding the reef to its list of sites that are "in danger".

Lexico/Oxford's explanation of *due to* doesn't help:

> Caused by or ascribable to.
>   Because of; owing to.

If I substitute any of those four phrases for *due to* in the quote about Unesco, it still makes no sense.

Comment: In this context, *due to = ready to*.

Comment: You need to consider the meanings of "due" and "to" separately.

Comment: It's perhaps not the best expression to use here; I'd choose 'scheduled/expected/ready/about [to]' depending on the level of certainty (that it will actually be done) I wish to convey. However: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/due) has << **due** [adjective] (EXPECTED) ... **B1**
expected to happen, arrive etc. at a particular time:
_What time is the next bus due?_ / 
_The next meeting is due to be held in three months' time._ /

Comment: _Their first baby is due in January._ ///
**B2** in due course {formal} [mandated/scheduled/expected/ready/about to deliver on something] at a suitable time in the future:
_You will receive notification of the results in due course._ /  _The present chairman is due to retire next month._ / [_The MPs are due to debate the new Brexit deal again on Monday._] /  _They backed out of the deal the day before they were due to sign the contract._ / _He's due to appear in court again on Monday._ >> This latter is the relevant usage.

Answer (score -1):

You can substitute it with **about to**, meaning that they are going to do it soon.